# Android - overriding android.content.Resources class

Tags: android

Can we override the `android.content.Resources` class, so that calling `getResources()` from anywhere in the application points to the overridden custom Resources object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ContextWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) and override its `getResources()` method to return your custom resources implementation.

For example, you can do something like this in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context wrappedContext = new MyContextWrapper(this);
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(wrappedContext).inflate(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(v);
}
```

This works, but it's not automatically "from anywhere in the application", you'll have to manually pass the appropriate wrapper whenever you invoke something that takes a `Context` parameter.

The `Application` class itself extends `ContextWrapper` and thus also has a `getResources()` method. If you override that in a custom `Application` class and set it up in AndroidManifest.xml, then anything calling `context.getApplicationContext().getResources()` will get the custom implementation.

Comment: It's not exactly I have want to do, but it solves the major part of the problem. I can use this solution to build a better one.